# HTML radio button CSS styling:remove default grey circle

Tags: html, css, radio-button

HTML radio button has grey circle around it when loading.
Any ideas how I can remove the gray circle around the radio button circle?

Answer (score 3):

You can use that property. But after it you need write your own custom styles for radio.

```
input[type='radio'] {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

For example. Here this circle is green.

```css
input[type='radio'] {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border:3px solid green;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
}
input[type='radio']:hover {
    box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px red inset;
}
input[type='radio']:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:60%;
    height:60%;
    margin: 20% auto;    
    border-radius:50%;    
}
input[type='radio']:checked:before {
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<input type='radio' name='a' checked/>
<input type='radio' name='a'/>
```

Comment: I'm not looking to change the color of the circle where you click. there's an unsightly gray circle around that circle, which loads when the page loads. As soon as you click on it, the that gray shading disappears. But I don't know why it loads when the page does, or how to remove it